# Nodemon not starting local server?

Tags: express, nodemon

I am trying to run my `Express` project but it won't execute.Following is my package.json file

[image]

I am writing following command in terminal but noting happens. FYI, I am in the right directory

[image]

Here is my `index.js` file

```
require("./models/User");
require("./models/Track");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/authRoutes");
const trackRoutes = require("./routes/trackRoutes");

const requireAuth = require("./middlewares/requireAuth");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(trackRoutes);

const mongoUri =
  "MY_MONGO_URL";
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});

mongoose.connections.concat("connected", () => {
  console.log("Connected to mongo instance");
});

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.error("Error connecting to mongo", err);
});

app.get("/", requireAuth, (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Your Email: ${req.user.email}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Provide content of the `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `yarn run dev` as I am using `yarn`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your script as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
 },
```

Then from the root of your project, you can start your server:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: ensure you have your express server correctly setup in your index.js file and listening on a port.